# LoRa antenna frequency

Tags: antenna, frequency, lora

I asked an antenna supplier if their 433 MHz antenna was compatible with a 433 MHz LoRa chip, and their answer was "NO".

Are there any variants when it comes to antennas with the same frequency? Or will any 433 MHz antenna work with any 433 MHz radio chip (if we take 433 MHz as an example)?

Comment: Yeah, antennas don't really care what communications protocol you use. Maybe he thinks LoRa only operates on 868 or 915 MHz? Or maybe he thinks that antennas he has are too narrow band to handle the CSS modulation?

Comment: The safe answer, if he doesn't know anything about the specifics of your equipment, is no. Some board-mount antennas need matching on board. Most connectable antennas are 50Ω, though some are 75Ω. The same with some ICs, some will need some matching, some will come out at a real impedance that might be close to 50Ω, or might benefit from a transformer. Read the datasheets for both IC and antenna, and then decide how much work is needed to get them to the same impedance. Once that's done, they are completely protocol agnostic. Check the bandwidth however.

Comment: Interesting document concerning 433MHz antennas: https://wireless.murata.com/media/products/apnotes/antenna.pdf

Comment: Could you share datasheet for your device and antenna? Antennas usually "don't care" what is being transmitted, as long as you can properly drive them (impedance matching) and it has the proper bandwidth.